# Citation: Sample mean as consistent and unbiased estimator of the expected value

Tags: unbiased-estimator, estimators, consistency

A reviewer asked for a citation that the sample mean is a consistent and unbiased estimator of the expected value and therefore converges towards the expected value. I know I can easily do the calculations myself based on the variance of the sample mean etc. However, since the reviewer specifically asked for a citation, I am not sure a proof instead would be acceptable. Also, I don't like adding proofs that have almost nothing to do with the actual subject of the article.

In most books I looked at, this fact is either only provided for the normal distribution (i.e. sample mean is an estimator of the parameter $\mu$), or included as an exercise.

Is anybody aware of a citation that I could use to support the claim that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator for any distribution (assuming of course expected value exists and variance is finite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbiasedness: Casella and Berger, *Statistical Inference, 2nd Ed.*, Theorem 5.2.6 p213-214

Consistency: Casella and Berger, *Statistical Inference, 2nd Ed.*, Example 10.1.2 *et seq.*, p468-469

Comment: Casella was my first thought, too. I wonder if it would be necessary, however, to go to peer-reviewed, primary literature.

Comment: @Dave I don't really know why the reviewer wants a citation for this, as I considered it general knowledge. So I just hope they are satisfied with this citation. The paper isn't about statistics and it is just a small part of the error estimation of the analysis, so I really believe this is sufficient.

Comment: @Dave Good luck with that.

Comment: @Glen_b that’s what I was thinking, that it would be quite difficult to find it in the primary literature.

Comment: I think a textbook will be adequate for what's essentially undergraduate work; it's not like physicists expect you to cite *Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica* and/or give the quote "*Lex II: Mutationem motus proportionalem esse vi motrici impressae, et fieri secundum lineam rectam qua vis illa imprimitur.*" when you just want to write $F=ma$.